# How to create a oracle view of the max sum of a sum of values of a column based on the values of another

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sum

I need to create a view in `Oracle 11g` that would take these tables:

**employees**

```
 FirstName | LastName | EmployeeID
-----------------------------------
    joe    |   shmo   |     1
    bob    |   moll   |     2
```

**salesData**

```
 Employee ID | commission on sale
----------------------------------
     1       |   $20
     1       |   $30
     2       |   $50
     2       |   $60
```

and then sum up the total commission each employee earned and return the employee who earned the most commission.

So using the sample data the view will contain the `employee id :: 2` or `bob moll`.

Comment: Well, what database platform is this for?

Comment: Why do you need a view for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you need

Create someviewname as view

```
Select EmployeeID, sum (commision) 
from employees
left outer join salesData on salesData.EmployeeID = employees.EmployeeID
Group by EmployeeID, commision
order by commission desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employeeID
FROM
  (SELECT employeeID,
    SUM(commission)
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY employeeID
  ORDER BY SUM(commission)
  )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Not sure why you want a view of that, but hopefully, you can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12g+, you can use `fetch`:

```
select employeeid
from sales
group by employeeid
order by sum(commission) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, one method is to use `rownum`:

```
select s.*
from (select employeeid
      from sales
      group by employeeid
      order by sum(commission) desc
     ) s
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: that looks right but could u edit it to use the second table I just added ? also I'm using oracle 11g

Comment: @NedCharles . . . The `join` is unnecessary, unless you have employee ids in `sales` that are not valid.